# How to split data into test and train after applying stratified k-fold cross validation?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, k-fold

I have already assigned columns to their specific k-fold using the following code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold, train_test_split

# Stratified K-fold cross-validation 
df['kfold'] = -1
df = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
y = df.quality
kf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)

for f, (t_,v_) in enumerate(kf.split(X=df, y=y)):
  df.loc[v_, 'kfold'] = f
```

Now the dataframe is as expected:

```
        alcohol  volatile acidity   sulphates citric acid   quality kfold
1499    10.9            0.36          0.73        0.39          6   4
1500    9.5             0.65          0.55        0.10          5   4
1501    13.4            0.44          0.66        0.68          6   4
1502    9.6             0.59          0.67        0.24          5   4
1503    13.0            0.53          0.77        0.79          5   4
```

But how do I split it into train and test split?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`StratifiedKFold`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html) will split the dataframe into a number of folds and return the training/test indices.
Each fold will have one part for testing (of size len(data)/n) and the rest will be used for training.

In your for loop, you can access the train and test sets as follows:

```
for f, (t_,v_) in enumerate(kf.split(X=df, y=y)):
  df_train = df.loc[t_]
  df_test = df.loc[v_]
```

As you can see the `kfold` column you added labels the testing data. The rest of the data should be used for training for this fold. I.e., for `kfold == 1` the training data is all other data (`kfold != 1`).